# qgis netlogo interface capacity

Tags: netlogo, qgis

I have a general question about the GIS possibilities on Netlogo.

I have a TIF file of soil moisture content across a country on QGIS. I am creating a Netlogo model in which I need to tell patches to 'own' a certain quantitative value of moisture content when input (geographic coordinate given by user) is of certain values. The model would then refer to the QGIS file and input in specific values according to the coordinates given.

I don't want to overlay the entire QGIS map into my model in Netlogo though, which is what I've seen so far. Is there any way around this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There's some hacks where you could turn QGIS into a server and use the Netlogo Web Extension to query. Or you can hack together a command line script using the Netlogo Shell extension. I would avoid these kind of shenanigans and use the  Netlogo GIS extension. You would need to convert your TIF file to an .ASC or .GRD file as those are the only supported formats for raster datasets. I'd start with .GRD as it will be smaller in size as its binary. Then use `gis:load-dataset`. The extent of your Netlogo world does not have to match the extent of the whole file - you can set your extent using `gis:set-world-envelope`. You can then apply the values to a patch variable limited to your world using `gis:apply-raster`.

If you'd prefer to do it point by point as users specify a coordinate as you mention in your question, you can instead just sample from an [xcor,ycor] pair, a patch or a turtle using `gis:raster-sample`

Comment: Thanks Stephen! But I did not fully understand your last paragraph. I now have an .ASC file, and I would like an interface in which the user can specify his coordinates, and upon doing so, the Netlogo landscape would apply the corresponding value (only 1 value would be applied) from the .ASC file onto all patches in the landscape. Is that what you mean by 'sample from an xcor ycor pair'?

Comment: ahh I got what you meant after testing it out. Thanks! :) But can't I input a list of length 2 consisting of the CRS coordinates, instead of having to specify the envelope of the GIS space to sample from?